# Firebase auth session cookie not set

Tags: javascript, next.js, cookies, firebase-authentication, server-side-rendering

I'm following [this codelab](https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-nextjs#5) to integrate Firebase Auth with my Next.js app. It generally seems to be working but I want to access the logged-in user from a server-side component.

I'm using this code (from the codelab) but the `__session` cookie is not present. Am I supposed to explicitly set the session cookie somewhere?

```
async function getAppRouterSession() {
  // dynamically import to prevent import errors in pages router
  const { cookies } = await import("next/headers");

  try {
    return cookies().get("__session")?.value;
  } catch (error) {
    // cookies() throws when called from pages router
    return undefined;
  }
}
```

However, in the cookies I *do* see what appears to be a Next-Auth token (`authjs.session-token`) although I'm not using Next-Auth (aka Auth.js).

In case it wasn't obvious I'm a total noob, to both Next.js and auth. I'm really lost and would appreciate any help here. I just want to be able to access the Firebase user from server-side code.